# Weird behavior of Media Queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have spent several hours trying to figure out what is the problem .. 
I have no idea what is wrong with media queries.
How css files are included in index.html

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Custom styles CSS -->
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <!-- Responsive CSS -->
  <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The part of my `main.css` file

```
#home {
    font-size : 1.5rem;
    background: url(../images/home2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-attachment: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: @backgroundHomeColor;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
}
/* === MAIN === */
.section-padding {
    padding: 6rem 0;
}
```

The `responsive.css` file

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1920px) {
    .personal-info{
        padding-right:180px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width : 1600px) {

}


@media only screen and (max-width : 1280px) {

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

    .portfolio-item{
        min-height: 150px;
    }
    .download-button a{
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand{
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }

    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a, 
    .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a{
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    /*about me section*/
    .biography {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 45px;
    }

    /*resume*/
    .resume:before,
    .resume:after{
        left:0px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    // Home intro section
    #home {
        font-size : 1.4rem;
    }
    .md-full-height {
        height: 560px !important;
    }
    // General styles
    .section-padding {
        padding: 222rem 0;
    }

    .social-icons ul{
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .social-icons li{
        padding:0;
    }

}
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
    #home {
        font-size : 1.2rem;
    }
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    #home {
        font-size : 1.0rem;
    }
}
```

The most problematic is `@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {`

It works sometimes, sometimes not, I have no idea what is wrong.

Consider this class

```
#home {
```

It works with media `320px,480px, 992px ....` but IT DOESN'T apply style for `768px` media query even with `!important`.

One interesting thing I've noticed that if styles are not declared in `main.css`
like this one

```
.social-icons ul{
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Is applied from this `768px` query, but if style is declared in `main.css` it is not applied, but only from `768px` query.

But if I move all these `media queries` styles to the bottom of the `main.css` everything works perfectly.

I have no idea what to do .. I have spent a lot of hours trying to find the solution for this `768px` media query.

Comment: How are you testing? If resizing a browser window... reloading the page after a resize can help.

Comment: I have tested it in different ways, resizing window, using developer tools, extension. 768px won't work completely (only styles that I described above)

Comment: The comments in CSS are `/* something */` you  have `//something` inside 768 media query

Comment: Give us a live example if you can. The most probable cause is that your styles are overwritten by some specificity in main.css

Comment: @blonfu , it works !!!! What is the problem, could you please post your comment as an answer, and I will accept it !!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using double slash `//` for comments inside 768px media query. This is not valid in CSS where the comments must be writed like this: `/* comment */`

You get a CSS syntax error and the block of code is not executed.

Comment: Thx, I was confused because of Sublime Syntax highlighting